# How to make a new dataframe with four columns based on an element of a list in R

Tags: r

So i have a list with 12 elements (one for every month).This is what January looks like: 
[image]

The columns represent longitude and the rows represent latitude. I now want to create a dataframe where there is one column for longitude and one column for latitude and the one column representing the value ie:

`avg   longitude latitude month
18.0  113.8W    36.2N     Jan
11.0  113.8W    33.8N     Jan`

I need to use this dataframe to plot the trend of 576 coordinate pairs for each of the 12 months (so 24 graphs by 24 graphs)

(additional question: should i make the coordinates as one column and represent it as (113.8W, 36.2N) or leave it as two separate columns?)

Comment: Please show us the structure of the list you have in R

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is called `list_df`, we can name them by months name using inbuilt vector `month.abb`. Using `lapply`, we can transform the matrix into a dataframe with name of the column, rowname, value at each cell and name of the month. Ultimately, we can `rbind` all the data together to have one dataframe.

```
names(list_df) <- month.abb

do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(list_df), function(i) {
   mat <- list_df[[i]]
   data.frame(avg = c(mat), longitude = rep(colnames(mat), each = nrow(mat)), 
         latitude = rep(rownames(mat), ncol(mat)), month = names(list_df)[[i]])
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` way.

Reusing `X` from @Edward:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(25, mean=12, sd=10), nr=5); X
rownames(X) <- c("36.2N","33.8N","31.2N","28.8N","26.2N")
colnames(X) <- c("113.8W","111.2W","108.8W","106.2W","103.8W")
```

And a list of such matrices:

```
ll <- list(jan = X, feb = X, mar = X, apr = X)
```

Then you can reformat with:

```
ll %>%
  map(~ as_tibble(., rownames = "lat")) %>%
  map(~ pivot_longer(., 
                     cols = -lat, 
                     names_to = "long", 
                     values_to = "avg")) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "month")
```

As for your additional question, for most cases, you're probably better off keeping latitude and longitude in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` and then add the latitudes. Suppose this is your data:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(25, mean=12, sd=10), nr=5); X
rownames(X) <- c("36.2N","33.8N","31.2N","28.8N","26.2N")
colnames(X) <- c("113.8W","111.2W","108.8W","106.2W","103.8W")
X
          113.8W    111.2W    108.8W    106.2W    103.8W
36.2N  1.0286035 12.766437  6.883963  5.847317  3.640007
33.8N 21.2551124 14.551648 14.369379 -6.068930 18.529475
31.2N 14.4679921 14.774468  6.584108  5.563189 16.412931
28.8N  4.6322846 17.368560 24.192276 32.460189 19.516291
26.2N -0.8000894  7.395144 13.741359  6.392376  9.220249
```

It's a matrix. Convert to a data frame, then stack it.

```
data <- stack(as.data.frame(X))
data$lat <- rownames(X)
names(data)[2] <- "lon"
head(data)
      values    lon   lat
1  1.0286035 113.8W 36.2N
2 21.2551124 113.8W 33.8N
3 14.4679921 113.8W 31.2N
4  4.6322846 113.8W 28.8N
5 -0.8000894 113.8W 26.2N
6 12.7664366 111.2W 36.2N
```

I think most functions in R prefer the columns to be separate. But you may need to remove the East/West and North/South.